# Programmatically Moving Emails Efficiently

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I'm writing a script that moves all of my read emails older than 2 weeks to a separate PST for archiving. Once it is acceptable, I'll execute it via a rule.

However, my current code takes a very long time to complete (about 8 minutes), while simply doing a drag and drop in Outlook is phenomenally quicker.

Does anyone know of a better way to move large amounts of emails? Maybe via accessing Outlook's index?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

$Outlook=New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$Items=1

while ($Items -gt 0)
{
    $Items=0
    $SourceFolder = $Namespace.Folders.Item($SourcePSTName).Folders.Item($Folder)
    $TargetFolder = $Namespace.Folders.Item($TargetPSTName).Folders.Item($Folder)

    $AllOfDem=($SourceFolder.Items | where {$_.SentOn -lt $SentMaxDate -and $_.Unread -eq $False})
    foreach ($Mail in $AllOfDem)
    {
        $Mail.Move($TargetFolder) | Out-Null
        $Items++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is not so much moving the messages (which can be optimized using Extended MAPI or Redemption (I am its author) to move all messages in a single call), but rather looping through **all** items in a folder - that is a huge problem.

Instead of looping, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` to provide a query that only returns the matching items.